# View classpath in jshell

Tags: java, classpath, read-eval-print-loop, java-9, jshell

JShell is a REPL for Java. To use additional classes outside the default JRE it contains a `/classpath` command to add a path to the current classpath.

Is there however a way to *view* the current classpath within the JShell environment?

---

Note that I'm using the following **early release**:

```
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+111)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+111, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Did you try `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun `-> System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))` returns `-Xdebug`. Something tells me they're not there yet :) Thanks for the idea though, fully skipped my mind.

Comment: That's what I also get, looks like they're indeed not there yet.. Meanwhile I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Did a lot of things to the classpath, but I seem only to be able to run classes that are in the boot class path.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This indeed seems to be a bug. Then again, I can see the class path using your method and a workaround. I can still not load any Java 8 compiled classes using this classpath though. Furthermore, I don't seem to be able to change it either, so I cannot confirm it shows the updates classpath. *I would expect it to use a different class loader*, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")) with "build 118 on 05-12-2016 (#4987)". It works.

Comment: @B.Singh Does it include paths that have been added using `/classpath`?

Comment: It doesn't assign the newly added in to "java.class.path" variable but it finds the added one. See below:

jshell> /classpath C:\temp\websocket-server-9.3.8.v20160314.jar

|  Path 'C:\temp\websocket-server-9.3.8.v20160314.jar' added to classpath

jshell> import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;

Answer (score 3):

The `/env` command, without arguments, will list your environmental settings, including classpath.